# how to send sms in background in android

Tags: android, sms, send

I am facing a problem in sending the sms.

In my application I have to send sms periodically with latest longitude and lattitude.
When clicking on send button I have to send sms to presaved mobile numbers with the updated lattitude and longitude for every 10 minutes for fixed number of times(suppose 5 times).But the lattitude and longitude is not updating frequently,so it sending  same location to all mobiles even when we change the location. How can I do that. Any Idea or sample code Please.

Thanks and regards:

Comment: Why don't you create a service which is send your current long/lat? Sending so much sms is not effective.

Comment: Can u please give me sample for that?

Comment: No. You must have a server to receive information from client. It's just simple post data to your server.

Comment: Why should I need a server. I just want to send sms to mobiles not to server.

Comment: Because most users have flat rate on data these days while flat rate on SMS is rare and SMS are expensive for most users. So unless user explicitly asks for SMS, they don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Sure how you are trying to implement i would have approached like this.

Using Alarm Manager create repeating alarm.. for every 10 minutes initiate Broadcast receiver and fetch current location details pass those values to the service and from Service send mgs's.

For your refrence **Note:this is not the complete solution you need change according to your requirments**

Reciever:

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,Service.class);
    //get lat/lng and pass it or get from service if u want
    intent.putExtra("lat","lat");
    intent.putExtra("lon","lng");
    context.startService(intent);

}  
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context) {

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

           calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

           calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
           am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }

}
```

**Service:**

```
    import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class YourService extends Service {


 @Override
 public void onCreate() {

 }

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  super.onStart(intent, startId);
  String data=intent.getStringExtra("lat");
  String data=intent.getStringExtra("lng");

  //or get the lat/lng here a
  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(number to send , null, text, null, null);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

 }

}
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample for that. How can I do that?

Comment: edited check that answer its not full implementation you need to create something like that... and don't forget required permissions,reciever and service in manifest file

Answer (score -1):

**Sample**

```
editBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        changeEdit();
        return true;
    }
});
```